# purrr syntax and map_depth

Tags: r, purrr, sapply

I'm trying to use purrr without piping for some consistency in syntax. But I'm running into the following trouble extract list elements at the same depth

```
## Example of a list

Henry_VIII <- list(name="Henry Tudor",DOB=as.Date("28 June 1491", format=("%d %B %Y")),place_of_birth="Palace of Placentia, Greenwich, Kent",
                   DOD=as.Date("28 January 1547", format=("%d %B %Y")),place_of_death="Palace of Whitehall, London")


Catherine_of_Aragon <- list(name="Catherine of Aragon", marriage_date=1509, end_date=1533, end_cause="annulled")
Anne_Boleyn <- list(name="Anne Boleyn", marriage_date=1533, end_date=1536, end_cause="executed")

Henry_VIII <- list(name="Henry Tudor",DOB=as.Date("28 June 1491", format=("%d %B %Y")),place_of_birth="Palace of Placentia, Greenwich, Kent",
                   DOD=as.Date("28 January 1547", format=("%d %B %Y")),place_of_death="Palace of Whitehall, London", marriages=list(Catherine_of_Aragon,Anne_Boleyn))  


sapply(1:length(Henry_VIII$marriages), function(x) Henry_VIII$marriages[[x]]$end_cause) ##works fine

Henry_VIII$marriages %>% map_depth(1,4) ## also works fine
```

But, the following throws an error

```
purrr::map(Henry_VIII$marriages, c(1,4))
```

Should I just use piping, or is there an obvious syntax error I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the function you need to apply i.e

```
purrr::map(Henry_VIII$marriages, `[[`, 4)
#Similar to
#purrr::map(Henry_VIII$marriages, ~.x[[4]])

#[[1]]
#[1] "annulled"

#[[2]]
#[1] "executed"
```

Or perhaps, in this case `map_chr` would be better?

```
purrr::map_chr(Henry_VIII$marriages, `[[`, 4)
#[1] "annulled" "executed"
```

Comment: How would I go a level deeper with purrr? For example if I nest a list for children, the lapply function would be `sapply(1:length(Henry_VIII$marriages), function(x) Henry_VIII$marriages[[x]]$issue[[1]])`

Comment: @MarkR Something like this? `purrr::map(Henry_VIII$marriages, ~.x$issue[[1]])`

Comment: Yes! So obvious now! I still find the .x and `[[` notations rather counter-intuitive. But I remember when the apply family made no sense either. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` from `base R`

```
lapply(Henry_VIII$marriages, `[[`, 4)
#[[1]]
#[1] "annulled"

#[[2]]
#[1] "executed"
```

Or if we need a vector

```
sapply(Henry_VIII$marriages, `[[`, 4)
```